# USB NFC message PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn fails with ACR122u and Android NFC in HCE mode

Tags: android, usb, nfc, hce, acr122

I have been developing a driver for a POS software to handle with NFC cards with libusb, using the endpoits Bulk In, Bulk Out and Interrupt In.
We use ACS ACR122u readers and Mifare Ultralight C tags.

When a interrupt in comes up saying a tag has been found, I perform an ICC power on (PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn message) and wait for the tag's **ATR**. With a MifareULC tag it works just fine:

```
PC > ACR : 62 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
ACR > PC : 80 14 00 00 00 00 03 00 81 00 3B 8F 80 01 80 4F 0C A0 00 00 03 06 03 00 03 00 00 00 00 68
```

So I get the tag's RID, card type, etc...

However, when I use my Android phone with an app running (implementing HostApduService) What I get is an error:

```
PC > ACR : 62 00 00 00 00 00 03 00 00 00
ACR > PC : 80 05 00 00 00 00 03 00 81 00 3B 80 80 01 01
```

What confuses me also is that, I also need to execute the SELECT AID command to specify my specific AID for the app. So... I also have these doubts:

1. In order to issue the SELECT AID, I need to know if I'm in presence of a device in HCE mode or not. It makes no sense to perform this operation when what I have on the reader is a tag. Therefore, I need to know what's the type of "thing" I have on the reader. That's why I issue the IccPowerOn to check on ATR.
2. Nevertheless, I also tried the SELECT AID command on startup after setting up some reader options (Using message PC_to_RDR_XfrBlock). Result... error (0xFE : ICC_MUTE - CCID timed out while talking to the ICC):

```
PC > ACR : 6F 0B 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 A4 04 00 05 F0 01 02 03 04 00
ACR > PC : 80 00 00 00 00 00 02 02 FE 00
```

So, I'm stuck here.

Basically what I, somehow, think I have to do when a "card" is present is:

1. Query the card to know if it is a MifareULC tag or a device in HCE mode
2. If it is a device in HCE mode, issue the SELECT AID command to select my app
3. Get UID and so on...

What's the best way for doing this?

Kind regards,

Carlos Santos

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't like this kind of approach but I managed a way to workaround the issue.

In fact, in case the PC_to_RDR_IccPowerOn fails when a device in HCE mode is detected, why not try next the SELECT AID command...

So, after receiving a response with an invalid ATR, I'm now sending the command SELECT AID. Now the Android app receives the package and answers OK ("90 00").

Anyway, if someone knows a better and more reliable approach, please be so kind to share here.

Kind regards.